# Find flow of function over polygon

Tags: multivariable-calculus

The problem:

> Evaluate $\displaystyle\int_{C} (x^{4}+5y^{2})\,dx + (xy-y^{5})\,dy$, where C is the polygonal path joining the vertices $\left[\begin{array}{c}-1\\0\\\end{array}\right], \left[\begin{array}{c}4\\0\\\end{array}\right], \left[\begin{array}{c}6\\4\\\end{array}\right], \left[\begin{array}{c}4\\8\\\end{array}\right], \left[\begin{array}{c}-1\\8\\\end{array}\right], and \left[\begin{array}{c}-1\\0\\\end{array}\right]$, oriented counterclockwise.

I know I can use Green's theorem and change the integral to $\int \int_D (y - (10y))dA$, and I think the center of mass is $(2.4 , 4)$ but where do I go from here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reinterpret your double integral, remembering that the $y$-coordinate of the center of mass is given by
$$\bar y = \frac{\iint_D y\,dA}{\text{area}(D)}.$$